# Duplicate/multiply rows in Dataframe if contain a certain condition/string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Please see the following dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['PMO', 10], ['LOL', 15], ['juli', 14], ['PMO', 10], ['LOL',
15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age'])

print(df)
```

I would like to iterate through this illustrative dataframe and copy/multiply the rows so that if a row contains, or matches PMO, that the row is duplicated underneath. Would this be possible, if so how?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small trick, check if Name equals PMO to get a boolean Series and add 1 to transform to an integer Series of 1/2. Use this to [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) the index:

```
out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Name'].eq('PMO').add(1))]
```

For a more classical way, use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = pd.concat([df, df.loc[df['Name'].eq('PMO')]]).sort_index()
```

output:

```
   Name  Age
0   PMO   10
0   PMO   10
1   LOL   15
2  juli   14
```

##### replicate rows with 'juli' 6 times:

```
N = 6
out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Name'].eq('juli').mul(N-1).add(1))]
```

output (**with only N=3 to keep it short**):

```
   Name  Age
0   PMO   10
1   LOL   15
2  juli   14
2  juli   14
2  juli   14
3   PMO   10
4   LOL   15
5  juli   14
5  juli   14
5  juli   14
```

Comment: I see, thank you. But now let's say that I want to copy the row containing juli 6 times every time that I encounter it. And leave the rest of the rows alone. Please see the adjusted code above. How can this be done?

Comment: Sure, see above